# GraphQL resolvers - when to make resolver functions async or not?

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I completed this [tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/0-introduction/) on making a graphql-node backend server built on Prisma2 and GraphQL. The tutorial doesn't explain why it writes some Resolver functions `async` and some not.

I thought that the `async` was added to functions that interacted with the database, but you can see this [resolver](https://github.com/howtographql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/resolvers/Link.js) gets data from the database but doesn't use `async`. But in this [resolver](https://github.com/howtographql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/resolvers/Mutation.js) it does use `async`.

Can somebody please explain why there is this seemingly arbitrary usage of `async`? When and why I should use it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: general (howtographql) tutorial can contain some errors/shortcuts (and it is not for explaining details), always follow specific (prisma) tutorial/docs - use `async` in both places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is read up on Promises. Promises are a way in JavaScript to encapsulate computations that are still ongoing. This is usually the case when you talk to an external service like a database or the operating system. They have been replacing callback style APIs.

In GraphQL a resolver can either return a value or *a Promise that resolves to a value*. This means, you can freely choose returning a value or a Promise, but if you call a database function like Prisma, you will get a Promise back, so you are kind of forced to stay "in Promise land", as there is no way to turn a Promise into a value. You can only chain functions, that should be executed with the value "in the future" (with `then`).

The last concept to understand is `async`/`await`. These async syntax is an addition to JavaScript syntax, that makes working with Promises easier. With `await`, you can stop the execution of a function until a value in a Promise arrives. Now, this looks like you are turning a Promise back into a value, but in reality, you function *implicitly* returns a Promise. For the VM to know about this, you have to state, that a function might use `async` by adding the keyword `await` in front of the function.

So when do you use `async` for a resolver? You could do it all the time, and the code would be correct. But doing it, even when you don't need to (e.g. you are not talking to a service) might have some performance implications. So it's better to only do it, if you really want to use the `await` keyword somewhere. I hope this can get you started with the concepts above, there is really a lot to learn. Maybe just go with your intuition and TypeScript errors until you deeply understand what is going on.